# Need a way to temporarily redirect STDOUT

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

I know how to redirect output in Linux.  Thing is, I have alot of output in my bash script and I don't want to type something like

```
echo $foo >> bar
```

over and over again.  I would much rather do something like:

```
hey, bash, for the time being put all your STDOUT in "bar"
echo $foo
.
.
OK, bash, you can go back to regular STDOUT now
```

I tried opening FD 1 as a file:

```
exec 1>bar
```

but couldn't get STDOUT back to normal when I was done.  Closing the file

```
exec 1>&-
```

gave me errors that I couldn't get around.

Any way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to first save stdout (by linking it on fd #4 for instance)

> exec 4<&1

Redirect stdout

> exec 1>bar

And restore saved stdout

> exec 1<&4

Comment: OK, learned something new about file descriptors here.  Any references on what it means to 'save' stdout (or another file descriptor)?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, close fd 4 with `exec 4<&-` when done with it.

Comment: @vladz Please update the answer with @Kusalandanda's reply of adding `exec 4<&-` and I believe that needs to be done _after_ the `exec 1<&4` command but am not sure.

Answer (score 9):

There are likely several ways to do what you want, but probably the easiest would be a subshell or command group:

```
( some
  commands
  you
  want
  to
  redirect ) >> logfile
```

The `( ... )` construct is a subshell; using `{ ... }` is slightly lighter weight as it's just a group of commands. Which to prefer would depend on whether you want variables assigned inside the group to persist afterwards, primarily, although there are a couple other differences as well...

Comment: Commands inside a subshell are run as in a non-interactive shell which is also why a `{ block; }` is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

#### Redirect a block

The simplest way is:

```
{
    echo "ALL THE THINGS"
} > OUTFILE
```

---

#### Redirection with file descriptors

```
function verbose() {
    local tmp stdout;
    exec {stdout}>&1 {tmp}>>OUTFILE # Save STDOUT; append to OUTFILE
    exec >&$tmp {tmp}>&-  # dup tmp to STDOUT; close tmp
    echo "ALL THE THINGS"
    exec >&$stdout-  # Restore STDOUT, close placeholder
}
```

Above, the `echo` will also go into `OUTFILE`.