# How can I read arguments from script that is being run in a alias

Tags: bash

Let say I have an alias

```bash
`alias kubectl='bash script.sh && kubectl'`
```

Is there any way to read passed arguments in `script.sh`
eg. If I run `kubectl get pods`, how to read "get" and "pods" in `script.sh`?

Comment: Use a function.

Comment: `alias kubectl='kubectl(){}; kubectl'` like this? While doing this the content this function will print will disappear with grep. Eg if this function will print Hello and I grep with pipe "Bye".. this Hello will not be visible, but I want that all the content this function prints should appear always regardless of any pipe grep or less anything

Comment: You can [temporarily redirect STDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238573/need-a-way-to-temporarily-redirect-stdout) to `/dev/tty` for the portion of the function without the final `kubectl` call.

Answer (score 1):

The millennium long advice is to use a function instead of alias.

> how to read "get" and "pods" in script.sh

Not possible with an alias, with a function just pass the arguments to script.sh.

```
kubectl() {
   bash script.sh "$@" &&
   command kubectl "$@"
}
```